# Moodle send email for inactivity

Tags: moodle

How can I create an API to send an email to the user when they don't connect on moodle after 15 days?

I searched a plugin but I didn't find anything, I also searched how create an API with laravel or symfony to be able to send the emails but i didn't find anything,

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ad-hoc database query plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/report_customsql) to get the student engagement data from the logs, and then set the report so that it automatically runs each day and emails someone/a system the results.  Then that person/system could create the required emails.

Comment: thanks, for reply , but i need send the email automatically @N